# ContextMenu event doesn't fire in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript

ContextMenu event doesn't work at cell phones? I use simple `addEventListener("contextmenu", handler)`. It fires in Chrome Dev Tools, but doesn't fire in real cell phones. I tried it in Android and Windows Phone.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Chrome / Browser on Android and which version of Windows Phone are you using?

It may be worth adjusting your code to see if the `document.addEventListener` function is defined, if not then fallback to the older 'attachEvent' function.

Try this:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        // handler
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
         //handler
        });
    }
```

Also, what is it you are trying to achieve by overwriting the default context menu behaviour?

When you say '...doesn't fire at real cell phones', does the `document.addEventListener` line not get hit, or does your handler function not execute correctly. Can you post your handle function code?

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest, I use code that you're listed above to attach the handler. I tried it in Android 5 and Windows Phone 8.1 (Mobile IE11). In real devices the handler will be never launched (even if I put only an alert inside). As I know, to trigger the contextmenu, I need to perform the long tap. I do this, but nothing happens.

Comment: Currenlty oncontextmenu is not supported for mobiles, thats why it wont fire. You should implement like @JonathanSmith said the longtap event by your own or use plugins